# How do I list yyyy/mm/dd directories in specified range conveniently in bash?

Tags: bash

If it's a single directory, I can use the trick like `{yyyymmdd..kkkkkkkk}` to select those in range.

But now the date information is contained in three directories,

is there any advanced bash trick that can do this job most conveniently?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -d1 */*/* | awk '$1>="yyyy/mm/dd" && $1<="yyyy/mm/dd"'
```

Comment: Do you think this is most convenient?

Comment: @user1608776: It is the simplest way I can think of.  If you need to do it a lot, you can turn it into a script.